# Real time comunication between bitcoind and web-application

Tags: php, cron, bitcoin, bitcoind

For example I have bitcoind and php-script. I need my script to know when there are transactions made on one of my bitcoin addresses to perform future actions, depending on this. The one solution I am thinking about is cron, however maybe there is something else. I see very often web-sites where there is no need to make deposit confirmation, e.g. trading platforms. Want to make something similar. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcoind has a `walletnotify` method that you can use. You can use it to run a command (in your case, execute a php file) as soon as your bitcoind gets a transaction. For some reason I cannot find a link to the bitcoin api but here are some links I fond on stack exchange and bitcointalk. I hope this helps you.

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24457/how-do-i-use-walletnotify

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=203438.0